# Independent or not Independent events.

Tags: probability, independence

The Sample space is $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ with uniform distribution.

Two numbers $i$ and $j$ in the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ have been singled out.

For each outcome $s$ in $S$ let $X(s)$ be the answer to "Is $s$ divisible by $i$?"

(take $1$ for "yes and $0$ for "no").

Similarly let $Y(s)$ be the answer to "does $j$ divide $s$?"

Prove that $X$ and $Y$ are independent in the following case:

a) $i=j=1 $

b) $i=2$ and $j=3$

My effort:
I am confused about the word "singled out". Does that mean that after taking out $i$ and $j$ they don't exist in the sample space anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $i$ and $j$ still exist in the sample space, it simply means that *before* you define $X(s)$ and $Y(s)$, you decide what $i$ and $j$ will be.

Now, the answer: If $i=j$, then $X(s)$ is equal to $Y(s)$, since the answer to

> Is $s$ divisible by $i$?

is YES if and only if $i$ divides $s$, and since $i=j$, this is true if and only if $j$ divides $s$, meaning the answer to

> Does $j$ divide $s$?

Is also YES.

Thus, since $X$ and $Y$ are equal, they are certainly **not** independent.

Comment: The question itself says that prove it that they are independent. So, they must be independent right?

Comment: @max well, they aren't. Now either the question is wrong or you misunderstood it or there is a typo.

Comment: Probability of X(s) is 1 which is same as of Y(s) which is also equal to P(XY) which is also 1. So, they should be independent according to the definition: Two events are independent if and only if P(XY) = P(X). P(Y)?

Comment: @max  Sorry, I missed the part that $i=j=1$, so yes, the two events are independent because they are both always true.